# Programmatically setting the context for a fragment for test purposes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment that I wish to write tests for

This fragment depends on the context of the host it is attached to (mainly to instantiate the database when needed)

My problem is that when I create the fragment for testing , I do not attach it to anything and therefore it does not have a context

I tried calling `onAttach` to `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` but as I saw after I inspected the `onAttach` code, it doesn't do anything with the context provided, it still gets it from the host

My question is either how can I attach it to a dummy host, or get the application context within the fragment without the fragment being attached to a host?

Comment: maybe try creating a Application 'variable' in Application class, instantiate it in onCreate, create a getMethod() for it & simple use MyApplication.getMethod(); in Fragment

Comment: yeah I read something similar somewhere else where you can get the context from the application and replace all my `getContext()` references to a static call to application's stored context, but I was hoping to avoid it cause I keep getting warnings about memory leaks and such

Comment: I dont think you can test a fragment without hosting it to a valid context.. May be you can try moving those logic to a separate class with an interface to make them testable..

Answer (score 1):

you simply cannot test a `Fragment` without the presence of any parent `Context` class (alike `FragmentActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`). this means, that you would have to add such an `Activity` at least to the debug `Manifest.xml` (in case this is otherwise not required)... or just test the `Activity`, which would usually contain that `Fragment`.

Comment: I guess that's the way I have to go, I was hoping to avoid this, cause I just want to test the logic but if there's no other way :/